langmap issue with [ and ]
I am using MacVim 1-727 and I have problems with mapping [ and ] with :help 'langmap'.
I have a Swedish keyboard and I set:
set langmap=ö[,ä]

If, for example, I open help pages and I use <c-ä> and/or <c-ö> on some tagged words nothing happens.
For testing purposes, if I set:
:set langmap=öi,ä]

then ö works as expected.
I also tested with diff and äc and öc work as ]c and [c.

In order to use language map for that purpose you should do (to navigate help the key to use is Ctrl-] and not ]):
set langmap=^\^]

Where:

^\ is inserted using Ctrl-vCtrl-ö and
^] is inserted using Ctrl-vCtrl-]

For your purpose I would try:
nnoremap ^\ <C-]>

Where:

^\ is inserted using Ctrl-vCtrl-ö

Remark: Some keys have a special meaning in insert mode (e.g.: Ctrl-w) in order to insert them literally you can preceed it by Ctrl-v.
Remark: The advantage of langmap over nnoremap is:

to map all the key commands in a consistent way by remapping the local keyboard layout to the English layout.
to apply also to register names in insert mode.


Thanks. I tried langmap=^ö^[,^ä^] and it didn't work; then &langmap = "\<C-ö>\<C-[>,\<C-ä>\<C-]>" return e357 in Vim9; I also tried the nnoremap ... as you suggest and it didn't work. In reality I really wish to map ] and [ because it is more general (think for example to navigate the quickfix list).

Thanks for your feedback! It seems to me that <C-ä> doesn't correspond to a character. Could you tell us what is the result of <C-v><C-ä> in insert mode (what is the character inserted if any)?

Here is a summary of my tests, all performed in insert mode: <c-ö> does nothing, but as soon I type a char (e.g. a) I get  ^\a if I <c-v><c-ö> I get ^\ ; Next, if I <c-ä> Vim goes back to normal mode; if I <c-v><c-ä> I get ^[. Question: why <c-v>?

Forgot to mention (and updated the main question): I tested with diff and the mapping works as expected. The problem appear when ä and ö are used  in combination with ctrl.

For what is worth, <C-ä> is seen as escape, which is what the character ^[ is. The easiest way to get the correct characters is to switch between US and Nordic mapping while inserting the characters and using the C-v to insert the result of the combination.
